# How can I shut down a Thread Pool correctly by use a while loop

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Here is some main code of my question，I'm a Student in China，My English is not good, please the excuse me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Thread-%d").build();
    ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            5, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
            threadFactory, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
    );
    // I submit 10 short task here
    // I want when ThreadPool finish 10 task, then shut down the pool
    while (!poolExecutor.isTerminated() && poolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount() == 10) {
        poolExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I want when ThreadPool finish 10th task, then shut down the pool，but the while loop does not seems to execute，the main Thread has been finished，but the core Thread of ThreadPool is still Waiting for task。

If I do not use the `while` loop and directly use `poolExecutor.shutdown();`. I can get the expected results. All the threads are finished and shutdown correctly.
But I want to know what's the error of my code.

Comment: Your while condition seems broken. `isTerminated` will return true when all of the tasks have completed. !isTerminated will be true but getCompletedTaskCount()==10 will return false until 10 tasks have been completed. So, if your 10 tasks have not been completed. You're while loop will not start. If all of your tasks are completed !isTerminated is false and your loop wont start. Actually, the first time. If all of the tasks are completed before the loop, then "!isTerminated" will be true and getCompletedTaskCount can be 10, since isTerminated is always false if there isn't a shutdown.

Comment: You're right, i find it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question, It just a logic error, Sorry waste everyone's time, the correct code is that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Thread-%d").build();
    ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            5, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
            threadFactory, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
    );
    while (!poolExecutor.isTerminated()) {
        if (poolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount() == 10) {
            poolExecutor.shutdown();
        }
        
    }
}
```

If I use the logical expression `!poolExecutor.isTerminated() && poolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount() == SORT_ALGORITHM_SIZE` in while loop, It will probably beacause `true && false` and exit the loop. Then I can't close the thread pool

Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Call `close` in Java 19+.

## `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` boilerplate

In Java 5+, you can use the boilerplate code named `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` given in the Javadoc for [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

```
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

## `ExecutorService#close`

Or, in Java 19+, call [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close()).

See [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.java) at OpenJDK.

```
@Override
default void close() {
    boolean terminated = isTerminated();
    if (!terminated) {
        shutdown();
        boolean interrupted = false;
        while (!terminated) {
            try {
                terminated = awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.DAYS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if (!interrupted) {
                    shutdownNow();
                    interrupted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (interrupted) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Tip: Unless you have a special need, use [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class to instantiate an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: My JDK version is 1.8.0_291，so I can't use this method，I have solved  my question，It's just my logic error，I'm stupid！

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issues with the `getCompletedTaskCount` method, but I'm not sure. I do know, that the suggested method of shutting down (and waiting for the imminent termination of) a ThreadPool is the following:

```java
ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Thread-%d").build();
ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    5, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(),
    threadFactory, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
);

// submit to poolExecutor

poolExecutor.shutdown();
// This is where the magic happens:
// maxTimeToWait is the amount of unitOfTimes to wait at max, before just continuing.
// javadoc: Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.
poolExecutor.awaitTermination(maxTimeToWait, unitOfTime);
```